# Alexa skill to change a variable on a website

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I have an alexa skill and a website. I need to send requests from the alexa skill to change a certain variable on a website.

for examble, I have a name on the website lets say "michael", I want to be able to change that name to "zack" from alexa.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa skill SDK allows you to perform remote calls to third-party APIs.
In your case, you can implement an API endpoint to change that field. Then you can call that endpoint with the data you need.

You can capture the name your user has been said.

By doing that, you would need to think how you will authenticate the user. Basically, you need to know how to match the user who is using Alexa with the user on your website. I don't think you want to change the name for the random user.